# Wall wiggly, how to make outlets straight?

Tags: wiring

The wall behind the tile is not flat in this area, and, even if it were, the tiles are quite variable in thickness. I am trying to get the outlets and switch to sit in the same plane.

The problem is not 'up and down' or 'back and forth' but rather 'in and out'.

The 'ears' on the three devices sit on the tile just as they would sit on wallboard. I am tempted to leave some slack in the screws that hold the devices to the box and pull them forward with the plate screws, thus depending on the plate to sit on the tile instead of the devices. Are shims typical?

[image: a frustration of outlets]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some methods to align switches in a multi-gang box?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/209841/what-are-some-methods-to-align-switches-in-a-multi-gang-box)

Comment: Not so much; edited question.

Comment: fair enough. vote retracted